# Send data from server(Node.js) to client(React Component) in GraphQL server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, graphql

I have use mongoDB, react.js, and nodejs in a GraphQL server. I just want to fetch data from mongodb in the server and send it to the client which react.js components are responsible. 
how can I do this?

Comment: Follow this tutorial :https://www.djamware.com/post/5cbd1e9a80aca754f7a9d1f2/node-express-reactjs-graphql-and-mongodb-crud-web-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one you can fetch your data from MongoDB.

Ex:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(URL) // URL:- pass your nodejs endpoint
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ results: data }))
      .catch(error=>{   
          if(error.response){
              alert("Error"); 
          }
      });
  }
```

Comment: should I put it in the react components?

Comment: Yes, in your react component. And whatever state you have you can use it instead of "results".